# How to implement this NN architect using tensoflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am new in this domain perhaps thats why i am confusing things. I am unable to get the required results as it shows very low accuracy which means i am doing it wrong.

[image]

The figure has a RNN structure and the model takes input (x), and passes through a NNAF (activation func.) and then with the help of a shift operator passes back a value to be utilized in the future (same as a vRNN). This diagram is more like a dynamical system in control theory.

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.model_selection
from tensorflow.keras import layers
data= pd.read_csv("u.csv")
#print(data.head())
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
import tensorflow
x=data.iloc[:,:3].values
y=data.iloc[:,-1].values
n_features = 1
n_steps = 3


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.1)
xtr=x_train
# create and fit the network
n_features = 1
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], n_features))
model = Sequential()

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=3, output_dim=1))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(2, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(2))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], n_features))
y_pred=model.predict(x_train)
#print(x_train.shape)
#print(y_train.shape)

print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]) # W - input weights
print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]) # U - recurrent weights
print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[2]) # b - output
m=model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to the Create a NN  using pytorch .
There are many types of NN , the three building blocks are :

FFN  :

1. Feed forward neural Net.
2. CNN  : Convolution neural Net.
3. RNN  : Recurrent Neural net . (LSTM is a type of RNN , you can use the below RNN code and change it to get the LSTM , let me know if you find  it difficult I will post the change)

Lets start with a FNN :
A FNN consist of three layers  :

1. Input layer
2. Hidden Layer
3. Readout Layer .

In case of MNIST , Input layer shape changes for each and also each has its own behaviour

1. FNN : Flat 28*28
2. CNN : Channel , 28,28 : Mostly for Images
3. RNN : Each step input  28 and total 28 time steps . : For Time series datatype [video , text , audio ]

The Code for FNN  is :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root="./data",
                            train=True,
                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                            download=True
                            )

test_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root="./data",
                           train=False,
                           transform=transforms.ToTensor())


batch_size=100
n_iters = 3000
n_epochs = n_iters / (len(train_dataset)/batch_size)
n_epochs = int(n_epochs)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               shuffle=True)

test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              shuffle=False)

class FeedforwardNNModelSIG(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,input_dim,hidden_dim,output_dim):
      super().__init__()

      #Linear Layar
      self.fc1=nn.Linear(input_dim,hidden_dim)

      #Non Linear Layaer 
      self.sigmoid=nn.Sigmoid()

      #Linear Layar(readout layer)
      self.fc2=nn.Linear(hidden_dim,output_dim)

  def forward(self,x):
      # Linear
      out = self.fc1(x)
      # Non-Linear
      out = self.sigmoid(out)
      # Linear (readout layer)
      out = self.fc2(out)

      return out

input_dim=28*28
hidden_dim=50
output_dim=10
model = FeedforwardNNModelSIG(input_dim,hidden_dim,output_dim)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

learning_rate = 0.1
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)

iter=0
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
  for i,(images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):

      ##1 Convert inputs/labels to Variable
      images = Variable(images.view(-1,28*28))
      labels = Variable(labels)

      ##2 Clear the gradients 
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      ##3 Get output given input
      outputs = model(images)

      ##4 Get Loss
      loss = criterion(outputs,labels)

      ##5 Get gradients wrt parameters
      loss.backward()

      ##6 Update paramters using Gradients
      optimizer.step()

      ##7 Repeat

      iter +=1
      if iter % 500 == 0 :
        correct = 0.
        total = 0.
      # Iter thorough test dataset
        for images,labels in test_dataloader:
          images = Variable(images.view(-1,28*28))
          labels = Variable(labels)

          outputs = model(images)
          # Get the max value of the prediction
          _,predicted=torch.max(outputs.data,1)
          # number of labels 
          total += labels.size(0)
          # Total correct predictions
          correct += (predicted==labels).sum()

        accuracy = 100*(correct/total)
        print("Iteration: {} , Loss:{} , Accuracy:{}".format(iter,loss.data,accuracy))
```

The Code for RNN is :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root="./data",
                            train=True,
                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                            download=True
                            )

test_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root="./data",
                           train=False,
                           transform=transforms.ToTensor())


batch_size=100
n_iters = 3000
n_epochs = n_iters / (len(train_dataset)/batch_size)
n_epochs = int(n_epochs)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               shuffle=True)

test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              shuffle=False)

class RNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim):
        super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
        # Hidden dimensions
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        # Number of hidden layers
        self.layer_dim = layer_dim

        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, batch_first=True, nonlinearity='tanh')

        # Readout layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Initialize hidden state with zeros
        #######################
        #  USE GPU FOR MODEL  #
        #######################
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).cuda())
        else:
            h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim))

        # One time step
        out, hn = self.rnn(x, h0)

        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
        # out.size() --> 100, 10
        return out

input_dim = 28
hidden_dim = 100
layer_dim = 1  # ONLY CHANGE IS HERE FROM ONE LAYER TO TWO LAYER
output_dim = 10

model = RNNModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()

learning_rate = 0.1
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)

seq_dim = 28  

iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Load images as Variable
        #######################
        #  USE GPU FOR MODEL  #
        #######################
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = Variable(images.view(-1, seq_dim, input_dim).cuda())
            labels = Variable(labels.cuda())
        else:
            images = Variable(images.view(-1, seq_dim, input_dim))
            labels = Variable(labels)

        # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        # outputs.size() --> 100, 10
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
        loss.backward()

        # Updating parameters
        optimizer.step()

        iter += 1

        if iter % 500 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:
                #######################
                #  USE GPU FOR MODEL  #
                #######################
                if torch.cuda.is_available():
                    images = Variable(images.view(-1, seq_dim, input_dim).cuda())
                else:
                    images = Variable(images.view(-1, seq_dim, input_dim))

                # Forward pass only to get logits/output
                outputs = model(images)

                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)

                # Total number of labels
                total += labels.size(0)

                # Total correct predictions
                #######################
                #  USE GPU FOR MODEL  #
                #######################
                if torch.cuda.is_available():
                    correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.cpu()).sum()
                else:
                    correct += (predicted == labels).sum()

            accuracy = 100 * correct / total

            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss, accuracy))
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to implement it using tensorflow. But the point is somehow I'm messing up the whole architecture of the NN but I'm unable to find my mistake in the given code. Can you please help me in that ?